# Can't reach proxy server when started through dockerfile

Tags: node.js, gulp, docker-compose, dockerfile, browser-sync

### Issue

I'm running a proxied browser-sync server through gulp inside an apache docker container. All is working fine, when I start the server manually (starting container, attaching shell, running gulp script through attached shell) and I can reach the server on the desired port. But when I tell docker to do the `gulp` command for me (either through `CMD` in dockerfile or `command` in docker-compose) the server starts successfully, but is not reachable and timing out. The output in shell is the same though:

```
apache-browsersync_1  | [18:35:01] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/gulpfile.js
apache-browsersync_1  | [18:35:01] Starting 'default'...
apache-browsersync_1  | [Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:8080
apache-browsersync_1  | [Browsersync] Access URLs:
apache-browsersync_1  |  ----------------------------------
apache-browsersync_1  |        Local: http://localhost:80
apache-browsersync_1  |     External: http://172.21.0.2:80
apache-browsersync_1  |  ----------------------------------
apache-browsersync_1  |           UI: http://localhost:3001
apache-browsersync_1  |  UI External: http://localhost:3001
apache-browsersync_1  |  ----------------------------------
apache-browsersync_1  | [Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)
```

I've already tried to use `command` in docker-compose and `CMD`, `RUN` and `ENTRYPOINT` in my dockerfile and even started gulp with a delay of 1 minute after the container has started up. Still same result, the server is starting up successfully but is timing out.

It seems like there is a difference between a command, that is executed manually through an attached shell and one thats beeing called from a dockerfile.

### This is my setup:

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  ...

  apache-browsersync:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: apache.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 80:80

  ...
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM php:apache

# change apache port from 80 to 8080
RUN sed -i 's/80/8080/g' /etc/apache2/ports.conf

# install node
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# install gulp
RUN npm install gulp-cli -g

# copy project data
COPY . /var/www/html

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

# start gulp
CMD gulp
```

gulp script:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

function defaultTask() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'localhost:8080',
    port: 80
  });
}

exports.default = defaultTask;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache is stopping, when running gulp in the same container, so I split up both services into different containers and referenced the apache server through the docker-compose container name in my gulp file.